# Text Fit In TextView

Tags: android, textview, text-size

I have a TextView that is going to display one single sentence.

This sentence could be shorter or longer, up to 200 characters for example, but could be more.

I am trying to fit the size of the TextView dynamically according to the text that will be written, but nothing that I have found so far works for me.

I have tried the [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/5535672#5535672) but it's not perfect for my needs as it adapts the text to a very small size and writing two lines, leaving a huge blank space on top and under the text.

EDIT: I see that in phones this solution works perfect. However, when I test in a tablet, it does not increase the text size to fill as much as possible. I am not sure, but I think it only decreases to fit. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Has somebody tried a different solution?

Comment: Do you think it could be possible to accommodate full text without re-sizing?

Comment: can't you use WRAP_CONTENT???

Comment: I want to fill as much space as possible, without leaving blank spaces. 
And no Armaan, I cannot use WRAP_CONTENT as it fits the textview's size to the content. What I want is to FILL_PARENT and then, adjust the text size to the maximum, filling all the space. Without trimming the text because lack of space, of course

Answer (score 0):

You could try [the AutoScale TextView third-party widget](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/autoscale-textview/).